# Get mapping dict from one-to-many (unpivoted) pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    foo bar
0   1   foo
1   2   foo
2   3   foo
3   4   foo
4   5   bar
5   6   bar
```

What's the easiest way to extract a dict from this dataframe such that each of the unique values of the 'bar' column map to a list of the values in the 'foo' column to which the 'bar' column's label applies?

Example desired result:

```
{
     'foo': [1,2,3,4],
     'bar': [5,6]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
In [82]: df.groupby('bar')['foo'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[82]: {'bar': [5, 6], 'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

for the uniqueness:

```
In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   foo  bar
0    1  foo
1    2  foo
2    3  foo
3    4  foo
4    5  bar
5    6  bar
6    1  foo  # <-- dupe
7    2  foo  # <-- dupe

In [93]: df.groupby('bar')['foo'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[93]: {'bar': [5, 6], 'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]}
```

unique:

```
In [94]: df.groupby('bar')['foo'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict()
Out[94]: {'bar': [5, 6], 'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```